# Как убрать белую полосу между секциямиб background image?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, как убрать белую полосу между секциями?
Вот код секций и их backroung image:

```
.header {
background-image: url('../img/hero.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
min-height: 115vh;
}

.about-us {
background-image: url('../img/about-us.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
padding: 100px 0px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Решил проблему, дело было в том, что я неправильно вывел картинку, без затемнения, а оно на макете было.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```css
/* Обнуление стандартных отступов у тегов body и html */
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Используйте класс .section для общих свойств секций */
.section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('../img/hero.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 115vh;
}

.about-us {
  background-image: url('../img/about-us.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 100px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Неа, у меня на все стоит *, *::after, *::before { padding: 0; margin: 0 }